# Restoring an Active Directory user using Restore-ADObject

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012

I am following this link https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd379509(v=ws.10).aspx that explains how to restore an Active Directory user using `Restore-ADObject`.

I am using the following command in Active Directory Module for Windows PowerShell:

```
Get-ADObject -Filter {displayName -eq "Smith, Steven"} -IncludeDeletedObjects | Restore-ADObject
```

I have confirmed that the deleted users display name was Smith, Steven however this user is not appearing back in Active Directory even though no errors are reported when running that command as suggested.

Please can someone point me in the right direction on how to get this user restored?

Comment: using samAccountName for filter is a more certain way to get the user you mean to get.

Answer (score 1):

For best results on restoring an AD user, I second strongline, you need to filter by **samaccountname** instead of by **displayname**.

For example,

```
Get-ADObject -Filter 'samaccountname -eq "art.vandelay"' -IncludeDeletedObjects | Restore-ADObject
```

Will find AD user Art Vandelay and restore the account to the OU it was deleted from.

If you don't know the AD User's samaccountname, run the below

```
Get-ADUser -Filter 'Name -like "*Art Vandelay"' | FT Name,SamAccountName -A
```